# Android: Filling ListView with ArrayAdapter in AsyncTask -> Shows only one item

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I am filling a ListView with ArrayAdapter in an AsyncTask.
But everytime it only fills in one item.

Could someone explain me why?

**onCreate**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connected_download);
    Log.v("string", "test6");

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            str_profil = getIntent().getStringExtra("profil");
            str_server = getIntent().getStringExtra("server");
            str_port = getIntent().getStringExtra("port");
            str_user = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
            str_password = getIntent().getStringExtra("pw");
            new connection_test().execute();
        }
    });
}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
    private class connection_test extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(connected_download.this, null, "Erstelle Vorschau. Bitte warten...");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... connection) {
                listftpitems();
            return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**listftpitems**

```
    public void listftpitems(){
    try {
        ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        Integer int_port = Integer.parseInt(str_port);
        ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(str_server), int_port);
        ftpClient.login(str_user, str_password);
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        System.out.println("status :: " + ftpClient.getStatus());
        System.out.println("FTPClient : " + "Offen");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    final ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_download);
    final FTPFile[] files;
    try {

        files = ftpClient.listFiles();

        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            String details = file.getName();
            your_array_list.add(details);
            Log.v("string", details);
        }

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(connected_download.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
            }
        });



    }catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**LogCat** (take a look to the Log.v("string", details); on listftpitems) so its correct

```
12-05 11:34:24.650: D/AbsListView(23249): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-05 11:34:24.650: V/string(23249): test6
12-05 11:34:24.695: D/dalvikvm(23249): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 64K, 9% free 13420K/14599K, paused 13ms, total 15ms
12-05 11:34:24.945: D/dalvikvm(23249): GC_CONCURRENT freed 29K, 8% free 13813K/14983K, paused 11ms+5ms, total 28ms
12-05 11:34:25.480: I/System.out(23249): status :: 211-Status of 'ProFTPD'
12-05 11:34:25.480: I/System.out(23249):  Connected from 213.55.184.193 (213.55.184.193)
12-05 11:34:25.480: I/System.out(23249):  Logged in as ftp031220
12-05 11:34:25.480: I/System.out(23249):  TYPE: BINARY, STRUcture: File, Mode: Stream
12-05 11:34:25.480: I/System.out(23249):  No data connection
12-05 11:34:25.480: I/System.out(23249): 211 End of status
12-05 11:34:25.480: I/System.out(23249): FTPClient : Offen
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): anon_ftp
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): bin
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): cgi-bin
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): conf
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): error_docs
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): httpdocs
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): httpsdocs
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): mivadata
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): pd
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): private
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): statistics
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): subdomains
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): vault_scripts
12-05 11:34:26.095: V/string(23249): web_users
```

**picture from my phone**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing everything in current code with wrong way like you are trying to Use `runOnUiThread` from `doInBackground` .change your code as:

---

**Change listftpitems as:**

```
public ArrayList<String> listftpitems(){
try {
        ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        Integer int_port = Integer.parseInt(str_port);
        ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(str_server), int_port);
        ftpClient.login(str_user, str_password);
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        System.out.println("status :: " + ftpClient.getStatus());
        System.out.println("FTPClient : " + "Offen");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    final FTPFile[] files;
    try {
        files = ftpClient.listFiles();
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            String details = file.getName();
            your_array_list.add(details);
            Log.v("string", details);
        }
    }catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

return your_array_list;
}
```

---

**Change AsyncTask as:**

```
private class connection_test extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
   ArrayList<String> temparrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(connected_download.this, null, 
                                 "Erstelle Vorschau. Bitte warten...");
    }

    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... connection) {
              temparrlist=listftpitems();
            return temparrlist;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
       ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(connected_download.this,
                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                              result);
       lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

---

**Change your Activity onCreate as:**

```
ListView lv ;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connected_download);
    Log.v("string", "test6");

            str_profil = getIntent().getStringExtra("profil");
            str_server = getIntent().getStringExtra("server");
            str_port = getIntent().getStringExtra("port");
            str_user = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
            str_password = getIntent().getStringExtra("pw");
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_download);
            new connection_test().execute("");
}
```

---

and plz read some basic of Android from :

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html

Comment: It's not working, because "The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<String, Void, String<.doInBackground(String[])"

Comment: means just change `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` to `AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: this will sure work but i'm not running your code on my end so maybe so short of problem occurs but this is the right way to use AsyncTask in your application.Thanks So much

Comment: Code is not crashing or anything. But there is still ONLY one item in my list :-/

Comment: then dear this is your logic for parsing data from web service i think now you can solved this issue your self easily .by using logs what u r getting from server. just debug listftpitems() function

Comment: I am getting every filename from server when i log it with log.v. Take a look at my logcat snipped, that I posted in the question...

Comment: It was a layout error... Thanks for your helping and showing how to use asynctask correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

> you don't have to create the `ArrayList` inside `AsyncTask` but adding
>   items to it inside `onPostExecute()` method.

try it the below code snippet.

```
 private class connection_test extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(connected_download.this, null, "Erstelle Vorschau. Bitte warten...");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... connection) {
                //Here you will get your arraylist with the Method listftpitems()
                your_array_list= listftpitems();
            return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(connected_download.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list);
   setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here it your Method.

```
public ArrayList<String> listftpitems(){
try {
        ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        Integer int_port = Integer.parseInt(str_port);
        ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(str_server), int_port);
        ftpClient.login(str_user, str_password);
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        System.out.println("status :: " + ftpClient.getStatus());
        System.out.println("FTPClient : " + "Offen");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    final FTPFile[] files;
    try {
        files = ftpClient.listFiles();
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            String details = file.getName();
            your_array_list.add(details);
            Log.v("string", details);
        }
    }catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

return your_array_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one

```
"V/string(23249): test6"
```

log, which means your loop runs only once. Check if

```
ftpClient.listFiles();
```

returns more than one file.

Comment: no, my loop doesn't runs only one time... `Log.v("string", "test6");` is only run one time. you have to look to the `Log.v("string", details); ` on listftpitems function